# Running Wireshark Lua dissector scripts outside of Wireshark

Tags: lua, wireshark

Our company has a big investment in Lua dissectors for all of the proprietary protocols our hardware uses, and which we sniff in Wireshark. This makes Wireshark a very useful tool for live analysis and for where a user was recording with Wireshark and saved the capture for later analysis. The same data that we sniff with Wireshark is also logged to binary files in a process not involving Wireshark. My task is to create a process to parse (dissect) the binary log files and output them as JSON, and I would like to leverage our existing Lua dissectors if possible and not rewrite dissectors (in whatever appropriate language), which will be a big effort to create and maintain in parallel with the Lua scripts. But I don't think Lua Wireshark dissectors can run outside of Wireshark, because they have dependencies on all of the Wireshark prototypes like Proto and Protofield, etc. that are injected by Wireshark at runtime.

Here are the possibilities I've thought of. Are any of them feasible?

1. Somehow I would find Wireshark Lua files with all of the logic that is
   injected automatically when the Luas are running in Wireshark.
2. I would write Lua scripts that would be referenced by our existing
   scripts, to overload the logic injected automatically by Wireshark.
   In both options 1 and 2, the Wireshark classes would return the
   parsed data to my program, which would emit it as JSON.
3. I would write a converter from our
   binary log files to Wireshark .pcapng files and spawn instances
   of Wireshark in a batch process, to consume and dissect the .pcapng files with  the Lua files and
   write the output to JSON or XML file.

**Update:** In a development potentially in favor of option #3, I can run tshark.exe (command-line utility which comes with Wireshark) to dump packets from a .pcapng file to the standard output. But only the equivalent of the Information column in Wireshark is output, not the dissected pane. If I specify one of our Lua files on the command line with the option:

```
-X lua_script:[my lua file]
```

I see the same sorts of errors from tshark that I was seeing when running the Lua scripts directly from Lua:

```
...dissector.lua:16: bad argument #2 to 'Proto' (Proto_new: there cannot be two protocols with the same description)
```

Comment: I guess all of them are feasable. if you're asking for a recommendation I'd say your post is against the guidelines as they discourage opinionated stuff. I ask myself why you would log that data binary and then convert that data to json using wireshark dissectors. why not simply log json right away?

Comment: The logging format was a technical decision made long ago before I was on the project and isn't going to change now. It's most likely so the data flowing over the network is logged byte for byte without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

I've already had this problem when I wanted to test the plugin's execution time. All I had to do was copy/paste the file into another folder, comment out the original file and run your command. This is because when you launch wireshark in any way, it launches all the lua plugins too.